# Dropbox-like automatic file versioning on Linux-based systems

Tags: linux, version-control, operating-system

Does linux have any utility or file system for tracking versions of files and directories like dropbox or ["Local History"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/large_lvcViewHistoryDiff.png) at [Intellij Idea products](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/local-history.html)? What I mean is when a user make a change in a file like /etc/ssh/sshd_conf, daemon will automatically detect the change after file is saved and create a new version for the file. After then user will be able to see what changes were done to the file or directory by whom and when. I am familiar with auditd and configure it to watch file changes which does not do versioning on files or directories. Git like version control systems are also not automated and need user do operation and doesn't create versioning automatically.

Comment: Are you working locally or may a server oriented solution be acceptable to you?

Comment: Until Eunuchs came around, nearly every major operating system had such an ability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at the filesystem [NILFS](http://www.nilfs.org/en/index.html) and see if it fits your need.

Comment: 2022: site seems to be dead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd hand-roll a solution involving `incron` or a custom script (running in backgroun) making use of `inotifywait` (packages `incron` and `inotify-tools` in Debian).

In either case, the script code triggered by "file closed after being written to" events (the `CLOSE_WRITE` event) would grab the new version of the file and commit it to a repository manager by the VCS of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Check out flashbake, which uses git. https://github.com/cmdln/flashbake/wiki